# UISearchBar override clear with refresh and stop similar to safari addressbar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

How to customize behavior of `UISearchBar` clear button to show refresh and stop icons and functionality similar to iOS Safari addressbar. I tried to get hold of UITextField, but it return nil

```
extension UISearchBar {
func textFiled() -> UITextField? {
    for view in self.subviews as [UIView] {
        if let textField = view as? UITextField {
            return textField
        }
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customize UITextfield of the UISearchbar - iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967291/customize-uitextfield-of-the-uisearchbar-ios)

Comment: The solution marked as duplicate doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UISearchBar {
    var textField: UITextField? {
        if let textField:UITextField = self.valueForKey("_searchField") as? UITextField {
            return textField
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```