# overriding UISearchBar's TextField

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I would like to override the textfield of my UISearchBar with my `CustomUITexField`.

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {
   // code goes here
}
```

I tried `searchBar.setValue(UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50)), forKey: "searchField")`. But it doesn't seem to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, can you please let us know why should you want to override UISearchbar's textfield? as it might possible there is some workaround instead of Subclaaing UITextfield.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967291/customize-uitextfield-of-the-uisearchbar-ios

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customize UITextfield of the UISearchbar - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967291/customize-uitextfield-of-the-uisearchbar-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the subviews of `UISearchBar` is not supported -- even if you manage to replace the text field by means of manually manipulating the subviews, this is not a stable solution and might break with any iOS update.

Depending on what you want to achieve with your custom view, I can suggest two alternatives:

- create a custom search bar component using your own text field
- customize the built-in text field, either by grabbing it via `searchBar.value(forKey: “searchField”) as? UITextField` or by configuring it via `Appearance`.